# AUTO_INCREMENT Bug in MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I encountered a very strange bug in MySQL, perhaps it is something which can be fixed easily but I didn't found any solution to this problem.

When I insert a new entry in any table, via php on the website or via phpmyadmin, the DB-engine inserts the entry with a new ID, but the AUTO_INCREMENT value stays the same when I jump between "Browse" and "Operations" even after 50 times or so. BUT when I jump once between "Structure" and "Operations" I can see that the value was increased by one, but really only then.
This is happening with every table in the whole MySQL Instance.

I need the auto_increment values before inserting the new entry because I am doing entries in other tables which are connected with the main table.

If screenshots needs to be provided, just ask:)

Answer (score 0):

It is not safe to get the id *before* generating it.  Instead, use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` *after* performing the `INSERT`.

The "unsafe" comes from two connections stumbling over each other.  The function call above is multi-thread safe.

(That particular function may be spelled differently in different APIs.)

Comment: Okay thank you, I will look into it. But this doesnt really help that the auto_increment does not increase automatically xD

Comment: Show us the `INSERT` that fails to increase the id.  And `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.